# Want Redirection If My HTML structure enclose with another parent html tag or id class etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I need javascript which work if someone add html tag or id classes as parent on my html structure then it should redirected to example.com

**Explanation** :> the below is my default html structure which contain two divs. and it has the parent **copyright** div...now i want that if someone add another tag as parent then it should redirected to example.com

```
<div id='copyright'>
  <div id='container'>
        <p>Copyright 2016. Designed By <a href='#'>Company</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The above is my **html structure**, and i want that if someone uses another html tag or id, clases etc as parent one, then it should be redirected to example.com example:

```
<div id='extra'>
<div id='copyright'>
  <div id='container'>
        <p>Copyright 2016. Designed By <a href='#'>Company</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now it should be redirected because it uses parent **extra** class. same if someone add another html tag like you see here.

```
<wrapper>
<div id='copyright'>
  <div id='container'>
        <p>Copyright 2016. Designed By <a href='#'>Company</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</wrapper>
```

It should also redirected because it uses html tag **wrapper** as parent tag and hence it should also redirected to example.com

I hope someone will figure out the script for me. thanks.

Comment: how will someone be adding tags to your html ???

Comment: i am a template developer and i offer premium and free templates, the free templates include copyright credit link, so often users when download my free template they include a parent div or any html tag and enclose my html structure with that. so thats why i want to prevent them from adding another extra div or any tag to my html structure. i hope you got it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(($("#copyright").parentsUntil('body').length-1) >0){
    alert($("#copyright").parentsUntil('body').length-1);
    //window.location.href="www.google.com"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<wrapper>
<div id='copyright'>
  <div id='container'>
        <p>Copyright 2016. Designed By <a href='#'>Company</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </wrapper>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, @parth your code is not working, check it here in my demo site source file. http://testingsite20.blogspot.com/  it is redirected even i dont add another html tag.....thanks.

Comment: @JohnBelly if your html parent tag `<html>` is their in your site it redirects

Comment: @JohnBelly can you comment out `redirect` so i can inspect html of your website. so i can help you.

Comment: @JohnBelly i have change code to check any tag found from your `<div>` till `<body>` if any parent element found then it gets inside condition and you can redirect.

Comment: check the demo site,i insert the script but nothing worked...http://testingsite20.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. raw DOM way,

   ```
   window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   //check for 
   if(document.getElementById('copyright').parentNode.id == "extra" || document.getElementById('copyright').parentNode.nodeName == "WRAPPER"){
       //redirect to example.com
   }
   ```

});

2. using jquery

   ```
   $(document).on("ready", function(){

   //check for 
   if($("copyright").parent().attr("id") == "extra" || $("copyright").parent().prop("nodeName") == "WRAPPER"){
       //redirect to example.com
   }
   ```

});

Comment: you make the script only if someone add "extra" or "wrapper" as parent tag, but we want for any html tag if someone add it...they will add some others tags like  <dream>myhtmlstructure</dream> <tagger>myhtmlstructure</tagger> so i want for any tag that uses as parent on my html structure as i given example in the question.